# 400 Bad Request for Ruby RSS gem

Tags: ruby, rss

I can't seem to get this `RSS feed` to work properly.  I've tried `Nokogiri` and now `RSS::Parser` and neither work:

```
a = 'https://phys.org/rss-feed/biology-news/biology-other/'
URI.open(a) do |rss|
  feed = RSS::Parser.parse(rss)
  puts "Title: #{feed.channel.title}"
  feed.items.each do |item|
    puts "Item: #{item.title}"
  end
end
```

The code is taken directly out of the docs: https://github.com/ruby/rss

The feed is valid, so I'm confused as to why there's a `400` error code.

What am I doing wrong?  Anybody have insight as to how to get this `RSS` parsed?

Here is the error:

```
/Users/user3/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/open-uri.rb:364:in `open_http': 400 Bad request (OpenURI::HTTPError)
    from /Users/user3/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/open-uri.rb:741:in `buffer_open'
    from /Users/user3/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/open-uri.rb:212:in `block in open_loop'
    from /Users/user3/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `catch'
    from /Users/user3/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `open_loop'
    from /Users/user3/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/open-uri.rb:151:in `open_uri'
    from /Users/user3/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/open_uri_redirections-0.2.1/lib/open-uri/redirections_patch.rb:55:in `open_uri'
    from /Users/user3/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/open-uri.rb:721:in `open'
    from /Users/user3/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/open-uri.rb:29:in `open'
    from /users/user3/app.rb:1856:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What line is raising the error? Please share the full error message, including the stacktrace.

Comment: @spickermann just edited now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web server requires the request to have a `User-Agent` set in the headers. Without such a `User-Agent` header it returns the 400 error message.

```rb
require 'uri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'rss'

uri = URI.parse("https://phys.org/rss-feed/biology-news/biology-other/")
uri.open("User-Agent" => "Ruby/#{RUBY_VERSION}") do |rss|
  feed = RSS::Parser.parse(rss)

  puts "Title: #{feed.channel.title}"
  feed.items.each do |item|
    puts "Item: #{item.title}"
  end
end
```

This code work for me.

Comment: Sorry, that did work, but not sure how to move forward with this.  I can't `parse` the result.  Put this into `Nokogiri`?

Comment: Ya `Nokogiri` for the win.

Comment: Made the code in the reply fully working. Nokogiri is not necessary in this case (and I think it is unnecessary)

Comment: `<internal:/Users/user3/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require': cannot load such file -- rss (LoadError)
 from <internal:/Users/user3/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
 from /users/user3/app.rb:1864:in `<main>'`

Comment: I modified my code to include that `agent` information.  How did you know that was the case?

Comment: You need to install rss gem `gem install rss`

Comment: Yep, been there long before now.

Comment: I found out because `curl` was working. Next a few experiments...